# Intellij Idea 14 shows rectangles instead of symbols

Tags: intellij-idea

I use Intellij Idea 14 on ubuntu 14.10. When there are symbols out of ascii in git commit message, rectangles are shown instead of symbols. What is the reason?

Comment: The rectangles inside should have a little hex number to them - usually that means a non-printable character.

Comment: Dear Makoto, didn't understand your answer.